# I'm trying to preview random photos on the site's share link

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random, math.round

I used this function in js to open the variable in the head of the html, I don't know if there is a solution or if there is another way to do it.

```js
function randomlink() {
  var links = new Array(3)
  links[0] = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vonkoln/clubenoturno/clubenoturno/pr.jpeg"
  links[1] = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vonkoln/clubenoturno/clubenoturno/pr0.jpeg"
  links[2] = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vonkoln/clubenoturno/clubenoturno/pr1.jpeg"
 

  var num = Math.round(Math.random() * 2))
}
randomlink()
```

In html `<meta property="og:image" content=links[num]/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Metadata is used by browsers (how to display content or reload page), search engines (keywords), and other web services."**

So changing it after the page has loaded will be useless. You will need to do this server-side wherever the content is being served from.

But if you want to try anyways, you will need to include more javascript in order to have a dynamic link. I can think of a couple ways to do it but I think your best bet will to be to just append the entire meta tag on load.

```html
<script type='javascript'>
function escreverLinks() {
  var links = [
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vonkoln/clubenoturno/clubenoturno/pr.jpeg",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vonkoln/clubenoturno/clubenoturno/pr0.jpeg",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vonkoln/clubenoturno/clubenoturno/pr1.jpeg"
];
 
  var numero = Math.round(Math.random() * 2));

  document.head.append('<meta property="og:image" content="'+ links[numero] +'"/>')
}

document.onload(function(){
  escreverLinks()
})
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your goal is but I imagine you are just trying to view one of the 3 photos at random when the page loads. If so you may actually be wanting to update an element in the `<body>` like an `<img>` tag.